Juypter Notebook Crashes When Tensorflow and Keras is Used
Kernel Stops Running
Whenever I use tensorflow, keras, or other libraries involving deep learning, the notebook crashes even though I installed the lasted version of these libraries. Anyone else have similar problems and what did you do to fix it?
I tried restalling the libraries again and closing and reopening the notebook but the problem persists.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
